# Need advice on sharing user specific documents from a LAMP server through a browser

Tags: ubuntu, lamp, webdav

my company has given me the task of setting up a system whereby our clients can log in to a server we house and retrieve their documents (invoices, items to follow, mostly pdf's) through their browser. I'm a web developer but I have no experience with setting up a server, however i'm keen to learn!

What I want to happen is a customer heads to our website (hosted elsewhere), clicks a link that takes them to a secure login for our webserver, they then enter their login details and are taken to their respective 'folder' on our webserver. Here they can download pdf's - that we keep up to date.

The main considerations are for it to be secure such that users can't access other users' folders and for users not to have to install anything to be view download their documents.

I'm setting up a pc to be a LAMP server right now, i've read WebDAV would be a good way to go but i'm not sure about how to get that working in a browser? Any advice or resources you guys can point me to give me a bit more direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider setting up Alfresco CMS, or a similar Enterprise class CMS solution. Alfresco, in my opinion is MS SharePoint in steroids. It has a lot of security features and makes it very easy to manage and share documents. Obviously, other security precautions will have to be taken, perhaps a VPN solution for your customers to limit access to the server. These are all details that will take time to workout. I would begin looking and evaluating CMS's first.